# File Access (read/write) synchronization between 'n' processes in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system, file-access

I am studying Operating Systems this semester and was just wondering how Linux handles file access (read/write) synchronization, what is the default implementation does it use semaphores, mutexes or monitors? And can you please tell me where I would find this in the source codes or my own copy of Ubuntu and how to disable it?

I need to disable it so i can check if my own implementation of this works, also how do i add my own implementation to the system.

Here's my current plan please tell me if its okay:

1. Disable the default implementation, add my own. (recompile kernel if need be)
2. My own version would keep track of every incoming process and maintain a list of what files they were using adn whenever a file would repeat i would check if its a reader process or a writer process
3. I will be going with a reader preferred solution to the readers writers problem.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel doesn't impose process synchronization (it should be performed by processes while kernel only provides tools for that), but it can guarantee *atomicity* on some operations: atomic operation can not be interrupted and its result cannot be altered by other operation running in parallel.

Speaking of writing to a file, it has some atomicity guarantees. From [`man -s3 write`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/write):

> *Atomic/non-atomic*: A write is atomic if the whole amount written in one operation is not interleaved with data from any other process. This is useful when there are multiple writers sending data to a single reader. Applications need to know how large a write request can be expected to be performed atomically. This maximum is called {PIPE_BUF}. This volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 does not say whether write requests for more than `{PIPE_BUF}` bytes are atomic, but requires that writes of `{PIPE_BUF}` or fewer bytes shall be atomic.

Some discussion on SO: [Atomicity of `write(2)` to a local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650861/atomicity-of-write2-to-a-local-filesystem).

To maintain atomicity, various kernel routines hold `i_mutex` mutex of an inode. I.e. in [`generic_file_write_iter()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.19.1/mm/filemap.c#L2658):

```
mutex_lock(&inode->i_mutex);
ret = __generic_file_write_iter(iocb, from);
mutex_unlock(&inode->i_mutex);
```

So other `write()` calls won't mess with your call. Readers, however doesn't lock `i_mutex`, so they may get invalid data. Actual locking for readers is performed in [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), so a page (4096 bytes on x86) is a minimum amount data that guarantees atomicity in kernel.

Speaking of recompiling kernel to test your own implementation, there are two ways of doing that: download vanilla kernel from http://kernel.org/ (or from Git), patch and build it - it is easy. Recompiling Ubuntu kernels is harder -- it will require working with Debian build tools: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

I'm not clear about what you trying to achieve with your own implementation. If you want to apply strictier synchronization rules, maybe it is time to look at [TxOS](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~porterde/txos/)?