# Is Python's file.write atomic?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Are `file.write` operations atomic in Python or C?

### Example

Consider the following two threads

#### Thread 1

```
with open('foo', 'a') as f:
    f.write('123456')
```

#### Thread 2

```
with open('foo', 'a') as f:
    f.write('abcdef')
```

Are we guaranteed not to get intermingled text like the following?

```
1a2b3c4d5e6f
or 
123abc456def
```

but instead get one of the two possible correct results

```
123456abcdef
abcdef123456
```

Note that there is a single call to write in each thread, obviously atomic multiple writes would require some sort of lock.  I'm also aware of file-based locks.  The ideal answer to this question is yes/no along with evidence/documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the underlying OS write() call might not even be atomic:

[Atomicity of `write(2)` to a local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650861/atomicity-of-write2-to-a-local-filesystem)

Comment: Yes, but according to your link, it looks like appending is likely atomic. (And append is what is used in the question.)