# Linux I/O: atomiticy of writes (and reads)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have read in some online doc pages somewhere that writes over files are atomic in the sense that if two process tries to write to a file (a single call to `write`), the linux kernel will do those write sequentially; e.g., a second parallel `write` request over a same file (by any other task of the same process or another process) won't start until the previous `write` has ended.

That doesn't mean that a single call to `printf` over `stdout` or `fprintf` over any file for instance will complete atomically, because such `printf` could be implemented by `libc` by several writes according to its buffer size or whatever, but any of these individual `write`s will indeed happen atomically (where the atomicity is actually no bigger than for 4KiB writes; e.g., a single `write`s of 9KiB will be splitted in two atomic 4KiB writes and 1 atomic 1KiB write).

That's was my mental model, but recently I have seen a case where two processes accidentally writing concurrently  over a same file left the file corrupted: each write was no bigger than a few bytes and always ended by an end-of-line (so one `write` = line). What I expected was to see intertwined lines from both processes, but what actually happened is that the file had no recognizable characters in it.

The process was just capturing the logging output of a daemon and writting every line captured to its standard output by simple calls to `printf` (one `printf` call per-line, since the logging output of the daemon arrived to the process in chunks of one-line each), but the command was launched by a cron with its output redirected to a file using the `>` bash syntax. It happened that two instances of the same capturing process were launched at the same time, and their outputs redirected to the same file.

Is my mental model about the atomicity of `writes` correct or wrong? and what about reads happening concurrently with reads?

Comment: Atomicity of file writes/reads is *generally* correct. And there are plenty questions on that topic (e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650861/atomicity-of-write2-to-a-local-filesystem)). As for "but recently I have seen a case where two processes accidentally writing concurrently over a same file left the file corrupted", then it depends what actually coded for these processes. The information your provide  about that scenario is **too vague** for say what is going wrong.

Comment: @Tsyvarev added another paragraph about the behaviour of the writting process.

Comment: Well, another paragraph gives much more details about the problem. But why don't simply prepare [mcve], with concrete code of the processes and with the concrete way you are running them from the cron? From my experience, corrupted output is easily reproduced on two simple processes which are run concurrently.

Comment: Two processes writing to the same file opened with `>` will keep overwriting each others' data. They will not merge their lines.

Comment: @thatotherguy I will try to write an example to reproduce this, but yes, if `>>` implies `O_APPEND` and `>` does not, and `O_APPEND` is what you need to avoid rewrites, then `>>` should solve the problem, right? You should promote your comment as answer.